# How to create subsets of multiple date ranges in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data frame with dates and numbers called 'df'. I have another data frame with start and end dates called 'date_ranges'.

My goal is to filter/subset df so that it only shows for the start/end dates in each row of the date_ranges column. Here is my code so far:

```r
    df_date <- as.Date((as.Date('2010-01-01'):as.Date('2010-04-30')))
    df_numbers <- c(1:120)
    df <- data.frame(df_date, df_numbers)


    start_dates <- as.Date(c("2010-01-06", "2010-02-01", '2010-04-15'))
    end_dates <- as.Date(c("2010-01-23", "2010-02-06", '2010-04-29'))
    date_ranges <- data.frame(start_dates, end_dates)

    # Attempting to filter df by start and end dates
    for (i in range(date_ranges$start_dates)){
      for (j in range(date_ranges$end_dates)){
        print (
          df %>%
          filter(between(df_date, i, j)))
      }

    }
```

The first and third result of the nested for loop is what I want, but not the second result. The first and third give me the dates and values for df between their respective rows, but the second result is the range from the earliest date to the latest date. How can I fix this loop to exclude the second result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looping through index

```r
for (i in seq_along(date_ranges$start_dates)){
    print (
      df %>%
        filter(between(df_date, date_ranges$start_dates[i], date_ranges$end_dates[i])))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `tidyverse` approach could be to create a  sequence between `start` and `end_dates` and join with `df` to keep only the dates which lie in the range.

```
library(dplyr)

date_ranges %>%
  mutate(df_date = purrr::map2(start_dates, end_dates, seq, "day")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(df_date) %>%
  select(-start_dates, -end_dates) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'df_date')

# A tibble: 39 x 2
#   df_date    df_numbers
#   <date>          <int>
# 1 2010-01-06          6
# 2 2010-01-07          7
# 3 2010-01-08          8
# 4 2010-01-09          9
# 5 2010-01-10         10
# 6 2010-01-11         11
# 7 2010-01-12         12
# 8 2010-01-13         13
# 9 2010-01-14         14
#10 2010-01-15         15
# … with 29 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Your data creation can be simplified: 
df <- data.frame(df_date = seq.Date(as.Date('2010-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date('2010-04-30', "%Y-%m-%d"),
                                    by = 1), df_numbers = c(1:120))

# Store start and end date vectors to filter the data.frame: 
start_dates <- as.Date(c("2010-01-06", "2010-02-01", '2010-04-15'))
end_dates <- as.Date(c("2010-01-23", "2010-02-06", '2010-04-29'))

# Subset the data to extract records with matching dates: df => stdout (Console
df[df$df_date %in% c(start_dates, end_dates),]
```